# Telerik access to RadComboBox inside RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, ascx

My code is almost identical to this demo:
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

The question is how can I access brand RadComboBox inside the RadGrid. If use it outside - it works OK, but if it is inside the grid, aspx.cs can't find the item by id.
The main problem I have - I want to create also a model field. And when the brand changes (for example Mercedes) I want to show models only for mercedes, and not bmw, opel and so on. I want the model to be select only like a brand field.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following resources on the matter:

[RadComboBox in RadGrid](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/how-to/Common/radcombobox-in-radgrid)
[Accessing RadComboBox in codebehind from a RadGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512302/accessing-radcombobox-in-codebehind-from-a-radgrid)

```
protected void OnItemDataBoundHandler(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
        if (!(e.Item is IGridInsertItem))
        {
            RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("RadComboBox1");
            RadComboBoxItem selectedItem = new RadComboBoxItem();
            selectedItem.Text = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["CompanyName"].ToString();
            selectedItem.Value = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["SupplierID"].ToString();
            selectedItem.Attributes.Add("ContactName", ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["ContactName"].ToString());
            combo.Items.Add(selectedItem);
            selectedItem.DataBind();
            Session["SupplierID"] = selectedItem.Value;
        }
    }
}
```